# How to solve this equation analytically?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, algebra

Why can't Mathematica 13 solve this equation in radicals?

`Solve[x^5 - 5*x^4 - 10*x^3 - 10*x^2 - 5*x - 1 == 0, x] // ToRadicals`

I also tried to use `Quartics` and `Cubics` options, but all in vain.

Although this is an equation of the fifth degree, it can be solved in radicals.

Moreover, one of the roots of this equation is real:

$x=1+\sqrt[5]{2}+\sqrt[5]{4}+\sqrt[5]{8}+\sqrt[5]{16}$

For comparison, Maple can solve this equation analytically.

Comment: it is 5th order polynomial?  [Abel–Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)

Comment: @Nasser, I don't agree with you. This theorem does not say that there is no analytic solution for fifth-degree equations. The theorem states that such solutions do not always exist.

Comment: The questions arise: what for? isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: `Solve[Factor[x^5-5*x^4-10*x^3-10*x^2-5*x-1,Extension->2^(1/5)]==0,x]//ToRadicals//Simplify`

Comment: @chyanog: How do you come to the `Extension->2^(1/5)` option?

Comment: @user64494 from: `?Factor`

Comment: @chyanog, but why did you choose that particular number $\sqrt[5]{2}$? Because you saw one of the roots of this equation I wrote above?

Comment: `V12.0.0` the command `Reduce[x^5 - 5*x^4 - 10*x^3 - 10*x^2 - 5*x - 1 == 0, x] // N` returns [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CvbF.png)

Comment: Also work `Extension -> Cos[1/5 ArcCos[3/(2 Sqrt[2])]]`